# excel upload in Angular 5

Tags: c#, angular5

I am trying to export data to excel in angular 5 by using below code. Excel downloaded successfully. But data in excel is showing like:

[image: something like this]

```
downloadReport(data:any){
        let blob = new Blob([data], {  type:'text/html' });
        let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "newfile.xls";
        a.click();
        // window.open(url);
    }
```

Comment: What is the in the data variable, console the value of data

Comment: (794) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0
:
{userID: 2, MaxPrice: "1130.00000", MinPrice: "", Date: "04 Jan 2016 ", Change: "", …}
1
:
{userID: 2, MaxPrice: "1130.00000", MinPrice: "", Date: "05 Jan 2016 ", Change: "", …}
2
:
{userID: 2, MaxPrice: "1130.00000", MinPrice: "", Date: "08 Jan 2016 ", Change: "", …}
3
:
{userID: 2, MaxPrice: "1130.00000", MinPrice: "", Date: "14 Jan 2016 ", Change: "",

Comment: if you have any demo on excel export  in angular 5 please provide the link..

Comment: I have the same requirement to export the excel then what I did is append the data in the table and export the data which is working fine, If you are searching for the same then I will post an answer with some sample data

Comment: yes.. please provide the link. i will try on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function in Typescript and call that function after calling your API for data fetch

function as follows:-

```
downloadReport(data:any){
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'Data.xls', { bookType: 'xls', type: 'buffer' });
    }
```

dont call this function on your button click call the function which fetches the data from API on your export to excel button

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) and [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver) library to export the table data in the excel file.

In HTML:

```
<table id="exportable" *ngIf="data.length != 0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let report of data">
              <td>{{report.name }}</td>
              <td>{{report.userName}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <button mat-button (click)="exportToExcel()">Download Excel</button>
```

First, Install [this file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver) NPM package using `npm i angular-file-saver`

And in TS:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'; /* import */
```

and the function:

```
exportToExcel() {
    var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById("exportable").innerText], {
      type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    var fileName = 'Test.xls';
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  }
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gletj)

Comment: @sumit glad it helps you!